# What does the name option in routes:[] actually refer to (Vue.js CLI3)?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

Ìm new to vue.js and I#m practicing routing right now. 
My router.js looks like this:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import Home from './views/Home.vue'

Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'home',
      component: Home
    },
    {
      path: '/about',
      name: 'about',
      // route level code-splitting
      // this generates a separate chunk (about.[hash].js) for this route
      // which is lazy-loaded when the route is visited.
      component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "about" */ './views/About.vue')
    },
    {
      path: '/myView',
      name: 'myView',
      component: () => import('./views/myView.vue')
    }
  ]
})
```

Now I thought the name option referred to the name I've given the "component".
For example, I tried out the following with "myView" view:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <myWorld placeholder="tester"/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import myWorld from '@/components/myWorld.vue'

export default {
  name: 'sklfdjns',
  components: {
    myWorld
  }
}
</script>
```

As you can see, the name is just gibberish. If the name option in the router really referenced this name in the component, Id expect it to fail. 
But it doesnt. Everything works just fine.

Then I tried out changing the name in the router option, but nothing changed as well.

So what does this name option actually do?
Unfortunately, the official Documentation wasnt helpful for me either..
https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/named-routes.html

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in docs router names are different than component names
purpose of named routes is to navigate without giving full URL i.e just by giving name and it's not reference to component name it's just name of your route

```
router.push({ name: 'user', params: { userId: 123 }})
<router-link :to="{ name: 'user', params: { userId: 123 }}">User</router-link>
```

both will navigate to user route which is '/user/:userId'

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the docs you posted, the name can be added for convenience. This can be helpful for longer paths or for iterating your routes into a menu for example.

To call such a route you then can use the name instead:

```
<router-link :to="{ name: 'home' }">home</router-link>
```

Another convenience example where i used the names before is iterating it into a menu with `$route.name`, you want readable names there.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Answer 1... the name mostly used when you want to push users from one page to another after something has happened

```
this.$router.push({name:'details'})
```

if the details name does not exist, you get an error

and also when you are also specific to a particular route, according to the first answer

Answer (score 0):

the name in the component specifics name of that component.

This is useful in vue devtool for debugging, or when you want to render a component recursively, you have to set a name for the component. For example, you want to render component `comment` inside the template of a comment (to display sub-comment).

The name in router is name of that route.

For example:
you have a route like this

```js
{
      path: '/',
      component: Home
},
```

when you want to go to the `root page`, you do some thing like this, right?

```js
this.$router.push('/')
```

What if I want to change the root path to `/admin`?
I will have to find all this code `this.$router.push('/')` and replace the path? No way!

Instead, I will specific a route name `name: 'root'`, and navigate through routes by name.

```js
{
      path: '/',
      name: 'root',
      component: Home
}
```

```js
this.$router.push({ name: 'root' });
```

Once I want to change the route path, I just change the path in `router.js`

The name in component property and the one from route has no relation.